# Is $xy' = y +xtg(y/x)$ a Bernoulli equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find out whether or not  $xy' = y +xtg(y/x)$ is a Bernoulli equation. I divided both sides by x but wasnt able to do much about $y/x$ existence of which undermines my confidence that this is indeed a solvable Bernoulli equation.

Comment: Assuming that tg refers to the tangent function, then no this is not a Bernoulli equation. That has a [very specific form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a Bernouilli's equation in y ...
$$xy' = y +x\tan(y/x)$$
$$xy' - y =x\tan(y/x)$$
$$\left (\frac yx\right )'=\frac {\tan(y/x)}x$$
It's separable
$$\int \frac {d\left (\frac yx\right )}{\tan(y/x)}=\int \frac {dx}x=\ln|x|+K$$
$$\ln|\sin(\frac yx)|=\ln|x|+K$$
$$\sin(\frac yx)=Kx$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=x\arcsin(Kx)}$$

Comment: Thank You, very detailed.

Comment: yw @Bak1139 ...